# Parsing file in Lua for specific value in table

Tags: parsing, lua

I am very new to lua programming and am trying to parse a local file on my pc and then save certain elements of the table/array into strings.

I have been able to get all the data and print each line of the file, except I am having problems when trying to get specific value and save them into strings or just print a certain line.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code sample:

```
function file_exists(file)
  local f = io.open(file, "rb")
  if f then f:close() end
  return f ~= nil
end


function lines_from(file)
  if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
  lines = {}
  for line in io.lines(file) do
    lines[#lines + 1] = line
  end
  return lines

end


local file = 'Stats.txt'
local lines = lines_from(file)


for k,v in pairs(lines) do
  print('line[' .. k .. ']', v)
end
```

Comment: Give an example of your problem with "getting specific value".

Comment: let just say I am trying to get the first line in the file and print that line, do I need to change my for loop when I am getting the values, or do I need to change where I am printing the lines?

Comment: You can `break` "read-the-file" loop after all the lines you need are read.

Comment: "I am having problems"  You have to say what those problems are. "say I am trying to get the first line in the file"  `print(lines[1])`

Comment: that is exactly what I am trying to do print(lines[1]) but I can not get it to work

Comment: "I can not get it to work " You're doing it again. [Further reading](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected. I copied the code to a file named `temp.lua`. Here is the output:

```
line[1] function file_exists(file)
line[2]   local f = io.open(file, "rb")
line[3]   if f then f:close() end
line[4]   return f ~= nil
line[5] end
line[6] 
line[7] 
line[8] function lines_from(file)
line[9]   if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
line[10]      lines = {}
line[11]      for line in io.lines(file) do
line[12]        lines[#lines + 1] = line
line[13]      end
line[14]      return lines
line[15]    
line[16]    end
line[17]    
line[18]    local file = 'temp.lua'
line[19]    local lines = lines_from(file)
line[20]    
line[21]    for k,v in pairs(lines) do
line[22]      print('line[' .. k .. ']', v)
line[23]    end
```